# How can I learn which css files are related this property?

Tags: css, sass

**edit:**

there is below code bottom of style.css:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

also there is a style.css map file.I added its code:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/azGno8Qb

---

I dont know anything about sass.I have a html file which made sass.I want to change its styles.However when I click the element on chrome, below link seems instead of css file on developer window:

/sass/project-sass/_header.scss : HTTP status code: 404

So, which css file is refered by _header.scss?

I need to change the element.

Also I included all css files but when I include a code snippet from this html file to wordpress, necessary properties doesnt load also there is no _header.scss on chrome developer window.

How can I include the sass stuff on wordpress?

Comment: Can you provide us code or folder map ?

Comment: @ThomasLamothe I added map file to my question.Also there is no header css

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question because you don't provide the architecture of your document and code. However :

`_header.scss` seems to refer to a "sub" style and it could be look like in the main style :

```
@import url("_header.scss");
```

But you can't put a scss file in HTML. You must compile it before and it will result a CSS file for example :

```sh
sass _header.scss header.css
```

and in your HTML :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/header.css">
```

Comment: I added map file to my question.Also there is no header css